# open .Jar file with java and not javaw via Double Click

Tags: java, jar, javaw

I have a .jar file that I would like to open via double clicking it and not the command line. When I double click it however it opens with Javaw.exe, I would like it to open with Java.exe when I double click it.

Note: I do not want to change the default program it opens with (Java TM Platform SE binary) because I still want my other .jar files to open with Javaw.exe.

Thanks

Comment: You need to change the file associations so that `java.exe` is used to run `.jar` files instead of `javaw.exe`.  Google for your OS type and changing file associates

Comment: Hi, thank you but I don't think this will work because as I said I do not want all my .jar files to open with Java.exe only this specific one should open with Java.exe

Comment: Can't be done.  If you're under windows, then you might try right-clicking the Jar and using `Open with...` and browse to `java.exe`

Comment: Ok if it can't be done that sucks. I read something about a batch file, not sure how that works, but could that work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have suggested changing the file associations, but you say you don't want other `.jar` files to open with `java.exe`. So your best option might be to create a batch file and double click that instead.

e.g. `my_jar.bat` with contents:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\Java.exe my_jar.jar
```

Comment: Ok awesome, how do you create a batch file ? But I guess I can google that. Thanks

Comment: It's just a text file with `.bat` as the extension.